# How do you prevent CodeRunner from prefixing its console output with [00m[00m[00m[00m[00m?

Tags: terminal, command-line, macos, console

There seems to be a connection between [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/)'s console output and your actual *terminal* prompt script, that is, if such prompt code is sourced from e.g. ~/.bash_profile (which CodeRunner reads by default).

I have a pretty fancy (read: *great*) terminal prompt ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUw4.png)|[code](https://gist.github.com/146c4b2fb491b9cab10d)) that seems to mess up CodeRunner's console output, leading to garbled `[00m[00m[00m[00m[00m` characters at the start everytime I run some code, even though it's error-free and regardless of language). I'm reluctant to change my prompt for the sake of getting rid of these annoying characters.

If I turn off **Invoke bash in login mode when running code** in CodeRunner's Advanced prefs, I'm seeing `bash: source: No such file or directory` instead…

So I'm stuck between a rock and a hard place, trying to get a clean console in CodeRunner…

How can this be fixed? (I've tried contacting the developer about this but I'm receiving no answer.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The culprit probably is line 88 in your prompt.sh:

```
trap 'echo -ne "\033[00m"' DEBUG
```

This will output an ANSI escape code to reset the colors and style before the output of every command.

From examining your bash script, this line seems to be unnecessary, because you are resetting the formatting at the end of your prompt here on line 76:

```
PS1="$status_style"'$fill \t\n'"$BY\$(__name_and_server)$Y\w$G\$(__git_prompt)$RESET$ "
```

I suggest you just remove line 88 and try it like that.

Somewhat unrelated to this problem, but I also suggest editing line 73 to the following:

```
local RESET="\[\033[0m\]"
```

This way you are truly resetting the ANSI styling, whereas before you were setting it to white.

Comment: The world would is a better place with helpful people like you, Gerry! Your help worked a treat!